# Display a SWT Browser programmatically from plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, browser, eclipse-plugin, swt

I am trying to open the internal browser of Eclipse ([org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/browser/Browser.html)) by calling it from an Eclipse plugin's code.

So far, I could actually instantiate one and I can "open" a URL (I can tell thanks to a log from the listener I set up). But nothing appears. As the shell is used as the Composite parent of the Browser, I expect it will just launch.

I could not find any resource on this specific issue, [most example snippets](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet128.java) not being about plugins.

Here is my code so far:

```
  final Shell shell = myActiveWorkbenchWindow.getShell();
  final Browser browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE);
   // set up listener to log the url when loaded
  browser.setUrl(getLoginUrl());
```

So, how could I make the browser appear (either as a popup or in my Eclipse window)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of thinking of "Browser" like an object with all its own window chrome, think of it like a dedicated panel or UI area that can contain HTML data.  The problem in the above example is that you are inserting a new UI panel into an existing widget (child widgets create themselves by taking the parent as a parameter to the constructor).

A better example to open a URL in a new window using the Browser object might be:

```
Shell parentShell = Activator.getDefault().getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell();
Shell myShell = new Shell (parentShell, SWT.SHELL_TRIM);
// Very important, generally parents must have a layout set to display children
myShell.setLayout (new FillLayout()); 
Browser browser = new Browser (myShell, SWT.NONE);
browser.setUrl (getLoginUrl());
myShell.layout();
myShell.open();
```

Comment: perfect, that worked. I guess I should spend some time learning more about SWT.